# Conditional For Looping in Typescript / Javascript based on value returned by a async call

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous

This is my requirement. My code calls a webserver (let call this as http://myapi/:id) which returns a json object.

My website which is a ionic app calls this api server 'n' number of times. The value of 'n' is user defined.

The expectation is that each api call has to be executed fully before the next api call is made and also the json object returned needs to be pass a set of conditions before the next api call is run. If the json object fails the condition checking then the execution of for loop stops.

The code should look something like this.

```
getObjects(count: number){
for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    myapi.get().then(val=>{
            if(val.flag == true){
                ;
              }else{
                break;
               }
     })
  }
}

getObjects(10);
```

Comment: Well after a lot of trial and error and reading up on async wait, async generators etc. This is what I have settled for.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice lol was I that confusing! Well I have a news feed for which I need to get data. Each news item is received as a json object when I make a get req.

Comment: The need was that I wanted one get request to complete before the next get request was sent. Just didn't want the server to be flooded with get requests and also there may not be any news to show. This data is part of the returned json. So I had to evaluate the json before making the next get call. Since for and while loops are syncronous. They were of no use. I also tried to use await. But that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found to work so far.

```
var i = 0;
getObject(i: number,count: number){

   myAPI.then(val=>{
     if(i < count){
       if(val == true){
            //dome some stufff
            i = i + 1;
            getObject(i, count);
       }
     }
   }).catch(err=>{
      //deal with error; 
   });


//User invoked call

getObject(i, 10);
```

Any improvements and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Calling a function within the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Been targeting your desired usage/call of method: `getObjects(10);` and came up with something like this:

```
getObjects(maxCount: number) {
    this.getObjectsLoop(maxCount);
}

getObjectsLoop( maxCount: number, count: number = 0) {
    count++;
    this.requestObject().then(
        (val) => {
            //do whatever with val ?

            if(count <= maxCount){
                this.getObjectsLoop(maxCount,count);
            }
            else {
                // this was the last request.
            }
        },
        (err) => {
            // stop sending request
        }
    );
}

requestObject(): Promise<any> {
    return myapi.get().then(
        (val) => {
            return val.flag? val : Promise.reject('Did not pass the success data flag/condition');
        },
        (err) => {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
    );
}
```

Try it out. You can declare the other two functions as a `private` method. You can actually just call `getObjectsLoop(10)` directly and/or just rename it with `getObjects` and remove the first function. I intentionally made it this way so that you can just have the last two functions declared as private and the Ts IntelliSense for `getObjects` will only show and allow one parameter (maxCount).

Comment: My end implementation looked very similar to your answer and had only two functions as suggested. Its funny that we ended up with same approaches and have two functions only. Or perhaps you are also inherently a lazy developer who wants to write as little code as possible . lol :).

Comment: I forgot to add just lazy just like me ;). Its also very interesting that you assigned value for count where you declared it. Ill keep that in mind for the next time I have to implement it. I have never seen it done like that. Cheer mate and thanks for the help.

Comment: It's just declaring a default value for `count` for when you don't put any value into that parameter. You're welcome.

Comment: And hey, less code means more readable code. If it's still proper to call it laziness, may it be called "ethical" laziness or something. hahaha. cheers.